# JavaScript: test vs exec

Tags: javascript

I would like to know what's the best way to check a string for example (mail, password ..Etc).

```
/^...$/i.exec(a)
```

vs

```
/^...$/i.test(a)
```

- **exec** returns value
- **test** true

**test:**

```
// 1° way
var mail = req.body.mail;
if(check(mail)){
```

**exec:**

```
// 1° way
var mail = req.body.mail;
if(check(mail)){

// 2° way
var mail = check(req.body.mail);
if(mail){
```

**exec** or **test** ? and what number ( 1° or 2° if exec)

**SOLUTION**

**test** is better for this case.

- it will surely be faster.

But the most important

- **test** performs all his work. While **exec** did not perform, because more can be done, but we do not need.
- Like said *Mattias Buelens*, using isMail() it's more logical: is an email: yes or no. While **exec**: is an email: email or null -> wtf ? lol

Comment: What do you mean by 'best way'?

Comment: 1st. Depends on what you're trying to do. Do you need matching/capturing groups and such or just validate to check if your provided string matches a regex? Also, the 2nd question is preference based, it'll have the same result. You should choose which is more readable and maintainable for you/your team.

Comment: there are two solutions, there are differents, so i think one of them is best **EDIT** @Fabrício Matté: just validate. Yes i think thant the first way is best because is more readable ans logic. (for you ;) )

Comment: `.test` will return either a boolean `true` or `false` so it's optimal for that situation. Both would return values which evaluate to `true`/`false`, but if you don't need to store matches or capturing groups then `.test` will do. =]

Comment: Ok, thank you man. Yes did not want to talk about micro optimization. But in this case.. Both have the same level of readability. But test is best for this way. More logical, and faster ! **EDIT** As you're here ;) i would like to know if i'm obliged to check if the variable isn't undefined same time as regex. Or you have a better technique ? thks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you only need to test an input string to match a regular expression, `RegExp.test` is most appropriate. It will give you a `boolean` return value which makes it ideal for conditions.

`RegExp.exec` gives you an array-like return value with all capture groups and matched indexes. Therefore, it is useful when you need to work with the captured groups or indexes after the match. (Also, [it behaves a bit different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description) compared to `String.match` when using the global modifier `/g`)

Ultimately, it won't matter much in speed or efficiency. The regular expression will still be evaluated and all matching groups and indexes will be available through the global `RegExp` object (although it's highly recommended that you use the return values).

As for the `if` test, that's just a matter of personal taste. Assigning the result of the regular expression test to a variable with a meaningful name (such as `isEmail`) could improve the readability, but other than that they're both fine.

Comment: It's a good explanation, even though there are some flaws. "`RegExp.exec` gives you an array-like return value with **all** capture groups and matched indexes." Not really. It'll return an array with the first match in the index `[0]` and its subsequent capturing groups in the next indexes. It doesn't return all matches/capturing groups, only the first match with all its capturing groups. However, you iterate through it with e.g. a `while` loop which automatically stores the `lastIndex` property in the regex object, as shown in the MDN link you provided.