# I am trying to execute regexp command but it is not working. How can I make it workable?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting false. Why isn’t regex.exec working?

How can I make it work so that the if loop will execute?

```js
const result = {
   latitude: 23.07696461,
   longitude: 72.59447369
};
const regex = new RegExp("^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,6}");
if(regex.exec(result.latitude) && regex.exec(result.longitude)){
    console.log('if  block');
}
else{
    console.log('else  block');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I can possibly help with this kind of thing but can you clarify what exactly is not working? What are you expecting to happen and what makes you think it is not happening?

Comment: @ChrisM Thanks for reply. I want to validate latitude and longitude. How can I validate it using JS regex function?

Comment: You need to escape the slashes, use `\\d` instead of `\d`. Also, the values have 8 digits after the point and your regex is set to match 1 to 6 of them (`\d{1,6}`).

Comment: (OT: `{1}` is superfluous.)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you are trying to test for 6 significant digits rather than 8 as you see in your examples.

A simple way to resolve this would be to change the regex so that it tests for 8 digits.

```js
const result = {
   latitude: 23.07696461,
   longitude: 72.59447369
};
const regex = /^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,8}/;
if(regex.test(result.latitude) && regex.test(result.longitude)){
    console.log('if  block');
}
else{
    console.log('else  block');
}
```

I also changed your regex to be a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_regular_expression) as otherwise you would need to escape the `\` characters.

However if this is supposed to be a *test* then you should be sure that you are testing your test with canonically valid data. Perhaps the latitude and longitude should only have 6 digits? Perhaps they will be variable? When dealing with data sanitation/validation it's important to know what your actual data constraints/requirements are, and ideally not just rely on assuming that certain examples and tests tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the test function:

```
const result = {
   latitude: 23.07696461,
   longitude: 72.59447369
};
const regex = new RegExp("^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,6}");
if(regex.test(result.latitude) && regex.test(result.longitude)){
    console.log('if  block');
}
else{
    console.log('else  block');
}
```

Comment: I expect function execute if block because it is a valid lat long.

Comment: Yes i get it but your latitude and longitude are illegal, the length of the number after the point needs to be 6, not 8 like your

Comment: Test method is more appropriate since it is, well, a test. But actually it makes no practical difference in this case because exec either returns null or an array of results which work as required in a boolean context.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use double backslash (`\\`) to handle `\d`, otherwise, it will interprete as `d` char.

Check this mate.

```js
const result = {
   latitude: 23.07696461,
   longitude: 72.59447369
};
const regex = new RegExp("^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\\d{1,6}");
if(regex.test(result.latitude) && regex.test(result.longitude)){
    console.log('if  block');
}
else{
    console.log('else  block');
}
```

**Note:** I changed the `exec` with `test` because you only need to check `boolean`.

Check this for more [explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004929/javascript-test-vs-exec).